# expanding text background color to fit portion of div box

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get the attached results.

[image]

The entire page is on a grid layout.

Every time I try to adjust the height to 100% to try to fill the tabs div box it overflows like this

[image]

```css
.tabs{
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.prints {
  display: inline-block;
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #ffffe6;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  text-align: center;
  top: 7%;
}

.shop{
  display: inline-block;
  background: #e95514;
  color: black;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  top: 85%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
  <div class="prints">
  PRINTS
  </div>
  <div class="shop">
    SHOP
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution here where you only rotate the content of the divs (`prints` and `shop`). I added `p` tag inside `prints` and `shop` so I can rotate the content of the div.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.tabs {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.prints {
  display: inline-block;
  background: black;
  color: #ffffe6;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center
}

.shop {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #e95514;
  color: black;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.prints, .shop {
  padding: 1rem 0;
}

.prints > p, .shop > p {
  transform: rotate(90deg)
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="tabs">
    <div class="prints">
      <p>PRINTS</p>
    </div>
    <div class="shop">
      <p>SHOP</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```